# Lettering.js not working

Tags: javascript, letteringjs

I'm trying to use lettering.js for the first time and I can't seem to figure out why it's not working. My goal is to get the project names under the photos on the right side of the page to use this script. Can anyone take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

http://dnb.khcreativemedia.com/

Thank you,
Krith

Comment: `$` doesn't look to be defined - are you using [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) somewhere?

Comment: Do you want to hire us? What have u tried...

Comment: just for debugging, try jQuery("...")

Comment: You're importing two different versions of Lettering for some reason.

Comment: & Welcome to stack overflow, you'll want to post a code snippet and something more informative than "not working". Questions on SO become records for future site visitors & were anyone to answer this, it would become unintelligible to future visitors as soon as your dev site disappears.

Comment: Thanks guys. Sorry for the newbie mistakes. Looks like cbuckely spelled it out perfectly for me and it is now working.

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of your `jquery.js`, you have:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

[jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) causes `$` to be undefined, so you'll need to use the following in your snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".project-title").lettering('words');
});
```

As shown on the [.ready() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), your function is passed jQuery as a variable, so you can name it whatever you want in local scope:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".project-title").lettering('words');
});
```

You can use the developer console in a modern browser to see the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: Thank you very much. New to js and learning as I go. This has been very helpful.